# iPhone SE, iOS10, why does it randomly *require* the lock code?

Tags: iphone, screen-lock, touch-id

I have my iPhone SE set to use my fingerprints to access it, and this is normally the way I get into my phone.  By at seemingly random intervals (absolutely no pattern that I can detect), the phone will require I enter the actual unlock code.  The phone has definitely not been rebooted, crashed, or anything of that sort.

What causes it to just randomly sometimes want the lock code?  It happens anywhere from once per week, to once every couple of months, but never with any pattern to the frequency that I can detect.

Comment: That does indeed look like a duplicate. I even searched but didn't find that question. The strange part is in my case I am absolutely certain that I have gone more than six days without entering my passcode before and not been prompted with this.

Comment: If you used TouchID frequently during those 6 days I believe it wouldn‘t ask

Comment: Aha ok, so then that would make sense.  I guess the combination of all the rules adds up to what appears to be a random interval, but actually isn't.  Thanks for finding that question for me!